# Unity ARKit/ARFoundation Multi-user. Find out when devices are synchron

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit, multiplayer

I'm using the ARFoundation-Samples(https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/arfoundation-samples) with Collaborative Sessions. So my AR-App can already place objects and synchronize them.

I don't completely understand the technology though. Is there any way to find out when the devices have tracked enough feature points or ar-planes to be synchron? Sometimes I place an object, but on the other device it doesn't show. I then scan more of the world and then it shows up on the 2nd device. I want to know when the devices are synchron so I can show an UI when the first user can start placing objects.

The only solution I can think of right now is to place an invisible object somewhere with a tag, and on the 2nd device check if this object appears. Then send via tcp back that it received the object. I really would like a better solution though.

Thank you for any help

```
var subsystem = session.subsystem as ARKitSessionSubsystem;
```

I've tried getting information out of the Subsystem.

```
subsystem.worldMappingStatus
subsystem.collaborationDataCount
```

but unfortunately there was no data I could use